# Why does parseJSON wrap my JavaScript object in a new object?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

Consider this JavaScript object wrapped as JSON:

```
vars = $.parseJSON('{"timestamp":1402720347,"AktiveSprak":{"en":{"ID":"en","Norsk_navn":"Engelsk","Lokalt_navn":"English","Bilde":"flagg_en.png","Aktivt":"1"},"no":{"ID":"no","Norsk_navn":"Norsk","Lokalt_navn":"Norsk","Bilde":"flagg_no.png","Aktivt":"1"}}}')
```

I want to iterate over the object AktiveSprak, but I can’t figure out how.

Now I can do `vars.AktiveSprak` but in order to use jQuery's .each function the object needs to be wrapped in jQuery like this `$(vars)`. Now, why can't I do any of these:

```
$(vars).AktiveSprak.each(function(){})
$(vars)[0].AktiveSprak.each(function(){})
$(vars).find("AktiveSprak").each(function(){})
$(vars)[0].find("AktiveSprak").each(function(){})
```

Comment: Why are you trying to use `$(vars)` at all? Your `vars` is already a reference to the object, so you can say `vars.AktiveSprak`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`$(object).each` can only be called on jquery objects to use with normal objects :

```
$.each(vars.AktiveSprak,function(index,item){});
```

http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/

> The $.each() function is not the same as $(selector).each(), which is
>   used to iterate, exclusively, over a jQuery object. The $.each()
>   function can be used to iterate over any collection, whether it is an
>   object or an array.

Answer (score 1):

Even when using jQuery, not every iteration must be performed with `$.each`. In this case, better use JavaScript's built-in `in` iterator

```
var s = $.parseJSON('{"timestamp":..., "AktiveSprak":{ "de":..., "no":... }}');
for (var lang in s.AktiveSprak) { 
  console.log( lang ); 
  }
```